# Conexión Exitosa, no envía data a la base de datos PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una conexión a una base de datos con PHP y MYSQL,
Me arroja conexión exitosa, pero no envía datos a la base de datos.

Previamente eh elaborado otro registro el cual funcionada de manera correcta, pero al hacer otro registro, me ha salido esta problemática.

Este es el codigo.

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$Matricula = $_POST['Matricula'];
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$ApellidoPaterno = $_POST['ApellidoPaterno'];
$ApellidoMaterno = $_POST['ApellidoMaterno'];
$Procedencia = $_POST['Procedencia'];
$Motivo = $_POST['Motivo'];
$Fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
$H_Entrada =  $_POST['H_Entrada'];
$H_Salida = $_POST['H_Salida'];

//aqui vamos a insertar datos
$insertar = "INSERT INTO horario_registro(Matricula,Nombre,ApellidoPaterno,ApellidoMaterno,Procedencia,Motivo,Fecha,H_Entrada,H_Salida) 
VALUES ('$Matricula','$Nombre',$ApellidoPaterno','$ApellidoMaterno','$Procedencia','$Motivo','$Fecha','$H_Entrada','$H_Salida')";

//Recorrer datos ya registrados y conectar a la base de datos
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

//Verificar si se guardaron los datos
if($query){
    echo"<script> alert('HORA AGREGADA');
    location.href = 'Horas.php';
   </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script> alert('DENEGADA INTENTE DE NUEVO');
    location.href = 'Horas.php';
   </script>";
}

?>
```

Esta es la conexión hacia la base de datos.

```
<?php

define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "sintesis");

$conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
// Verificamos que haga la conexion
if($conexion){
    echo ("Conexión Exitosa");

}else{
    echo("Conexion Denegada");
}

?>
```

Comment: Pues primero que nada, no estás mostrando como haces la conexion. Segundo, que dice el error log de apache ??

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta añadiendo este código por favor? Es solo para tener una mejor lectura. Otra cosa, que mensaje de error te devuelve??

Comment: @Alexci - Me devuelve el mensaje de "Conexión exitosa" pero no manda valores a la base de datos

Comment: @Excorpion ya modifique el código mostrando la conexión, Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: @Excorpion - no me manda errores, simplemente se loguea de nuevo, me voto el mensaje que "DENEGADA INTENTE DE NUEVO"

Comment: Repito... el archivo error.log, que esta dentro de la carpeta logs, dentro de la carpeta del Apache. Ese archivo contiene las respuestas del servidor... es lo mismo que vas a mostrar si haces lo que dice alexi.

Comment: @Excorpion okay

Comment: Eso no era para ti alexi XD era para el OP, tu comentario era correcto jaj

Comment: @Armando añade en tu `else` un `echo mysqli_error($conexion)` para ver que error te da al ejecutar el query (de nuevo haha)

Comment: Conexión ExitosaYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '','Lara','Universidad Autónoma de Baja California','Asistencia','30-09-2021'...' at line 2

Me arroja eso

Comment: Vez que ahora menciona el error, la sintaxis SQL está mal. Y es que al apellido paterno le falta una comilla XD

Comment: A la bestia, Muchas Gracias ya quedo.!!

Comment: @Excorpion cierto hahaha

Comment: @Excorpion Buen día bro, tienes alguna idea de hacer tablas relacionadas con o como mandar a traer datos de tablas distintas a una sola.

Comment: @Armando Buenas, si, el uso de JOIN. Traes los datos de las tablas que necesites.

Comment: @Excorpion Muchas Gracias bro!

Comment: En caso de tener problemas aprendiendo el uso de JOIN, haces otra pregunta.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias bro.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al analizar correctamente los procesos PHP se dio con el sgte error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '','Lara','Universidad Autónoma de Baja California','Asistencia','30-09-2021'...' at line 2

Lo que significa que tienes un error en la sintaxis de la consulta.

```
$insertar = "INSERT INTO horario_registro
(Matricula, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Procedencia, Motivo, Fecha, H_Entrada, H_Salida) 
VALUES ('$Matricula','$Nombre',$ApellidoPaterno','$ApellidoMaterno','$Procedencia','$Motivo','$Fecha','$H_Entrada','$H_Salida')";
```

Como ves, en $ApellidoPaterno, luego del VALUE, falta la comilla inicial.
Ahora aparece como `$ApellidoPaterno'` y deberia ser `'$ApellidoPaterno'`

Comment: Gracias por el consejo que me has otorgado, lo tendré en practica.!

Comment: @Armando Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta para que el caso quede cerrado. Mira que pasa como con Seba que agrego una respuesta cuando el tema ya se resolvio.

Answer (score 1):

Mi recomendación es que las variables esten todas en minisculas, todo, hasta los input.

Teniendo en cuenta eso hice una prueba en mi servidor y funciona bien. Debes tener un error tipográfico.

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "pruebas"); // tu base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error de conexion: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$matricula = $_POST['matricula']; // minuscula
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$ApellidoPaterno = $_POST['ApellidoPaterno'];
$ApellidoMaterno = $_POST['ApellidoMaterno'];
$Procedencia = $_POST['Procedencia'];
$Motivo = $_POST['Motivo'];
$Fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
$H_Entrada =  $_POST['H_Entrada'];
$H_Salida = $_POST['H_Salida'];

// $insertar = "INSERT INTO horario_registro(matricula, ....) VALUES ('".$matricula."', ...)";


// mi prueba

$nombre = "Pedro";
$pass = "1234";
$email = "pedro@gmail.com";

$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, pass, email) VALUES ('".$nombre."' , '".$pass."', '".$email."')";


$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```